# iOS UITableViewAutomaticDimension RowHeight Poor Performance / Jumping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I'm building a basic table view on iOS 8. I watched the WWDC '14 video on the topic of autosizing cells and am trying to reproduce the concept, but am having some issues. On viewDidLoad: I am calling:

```
//estimate for my cells though they may vary

self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300.0;

self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

When my view and table load up, performance is ok. When I click on a cell, the program takes me to a detail view. When I hit the back button on that view and return to the table view, that's when things start acting weird. The cells then start 'jumping' while I am scrolling. By jumping I mean that they don't scroll smoothly - they tend to jerk or jump from one place to the next.

I should add that memory is not a concern since the cells are being reused and there is little data in the background. The constraints on my cells (in storyboard file) are also blue and I am seeing no autolayout constraint exceptions in the debugger.

Has anyone else seen this kind of behavior with ***UITableViewAutomaticDimension***? Is it just an Apple bug or is there more to it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing same issue? any workaround?

Comment: @AhmadRaza What I ended up doing was going back to hand coded cells to ensure full control over layout and function. So basically, instead of using interface builder, I just lay out all the elements of the cell in code and then override tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: to tell the tableView how tall each cell will be.

Comment: I filed a bug with apple (over this behavior) and they confirmed that it was a bug (and a duplicate of one already filed) but did not provide any more information than that (pretty annoying). So I am assuming UITableViewAutomaticDimesion is known to be a bit buggy. I'd avoid it if possible for now.

Comment: I've implemented the example from WWDC2014 to demonstrate this issue, it's available here: https://github.com/IndieGoGo/WWDC-Dynamic-Type-Jumpy-Scroll-Issue
Also filed a bug with no response.

Answer (score 6):

I have found weird issue using the line `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`

But then, everything came a lot better when I replaced it with the delegates method. In your case would be :

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 300.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ADD one more delegate method to the code

**- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ return Approxheight;}**

it will load uitableView early than current time.
i hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In **cellForRowAtIndexPath** add below line

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```